# Rudimentary PHP upload script not producing desired result

Tags: php

My goal isn't perfection right now, it's functionality. I'll add visuals and security later, but for now all I'd like to be able to do is restrict uploads to .mp3 files, and product a URL to the file after the upload.

Currently, PHP displays the intended echo results, but the file isn't in `/var/www/html/upload`, as it should be.

## HTML (The part in question, at least.)

upload.html

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file"><strong>File:</strong></label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

## PHP (Every bit of it.)

upload_file.php

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

## The PHP Result

Checking `upload/`, the directory is empty.

```
Upload: hintro.mp3
Type: audio/mp3
Size: 390.0947265625 kB
Temp file: /tmp/phpnMYOou
Stored in: upload/hintro.mp3
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: So what problem are you actually having?  Are you getting errors?  Have you done any debugging on your own to help narrow down the problem? What is the full path where you expect the upload file to be located?  Where is that relative to where this script is being executed from?

Comment: Does PHP have write permission for the `upload` directory?

Comment: Be careful about the location of the `upload` folder. I'd probably change it to `__DIR__ . '/upload/' . $_FILES['file']['name']` provided it's in the same parent directory as your script. Also, you should be checking the return value of [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: Mike, the problem is that the file doesn't end up where it should be. I'd like it in ....../html/upload/, but that doesn't seem to want to happen. The full path would be /var/www/html/upload/hintro.mp3. The script is in in ......./html/. I'm not getting any errors, and I'm entirely new to the language, so my debugging has been minimal at best. Since everything else in the script works, it seems like the most nested if;else is the issue, where the file is actually moved.

Comment: Mark, yes, file permissions are 777, allowing read/write access for everyone. That was changed in Filezilla.

Comment: Phil, I'll see if that solves anything. Thanks to everyone for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your directory structure looks like this

```
parent-folder/
    |-upload/
    |-upload.html
    |-upload_file.php
```

try this

```
<?php
// Remove these two lines when you've finished development
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

if (!($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_FILES['file']))) {
    throw new Exception('Only accepting file uploads via POST');
}

$file = $_FILES['file'];
if ($file['error'] > 0) {
    throw new Exception('File upload error', $file['error']);
}
if ($file['type'] != 'audio/mp3') {
    throw new Exception('Invalid file');
}

$dest = __DIR__ . '/upload/' . $file['name'];

if (file_exists($dest)) {
    throw new Exception(sprintf('%s already exists', basename($dest)));
}
if (!is_writable(dirname($dest))) {
    throw new Exception(sprintf('%s is not writable', dirname($dest)));
}

if (!move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $dest)) {
    throw new Exception(sprintf('Error moving uploaded file from %s to %s',
        $file['tmp_name'], $dest));
}

echo 'Upload: ',    $file['name'],     '<br>',
     'Type: ',      $file['type'],     '<br>',
     'Size: ',      $file['size'],     '<br>',
     'Temp file: ', $file['tmp_name'], '<br>',
     'Stored in: ', $dest;
```

Comment: Yeah, missed a `)` on line 1. Fixed now. You shouldn't need a closing `?>`

Comment: Getting plain text starting at the 0 in `if ($file['error'] > 0) {`.

http://pastebin.com/q3eBqt9q

EDIT: Sorry, didn't see your reply, so I deleted my other comment. Do I need the opening <?, at all? Or does the file's .php ending carry all the information necessary?

EDIT 2: Nevermind, you added the opening <?php. Everything following the > 0 is still plain text, though. I'm stumped.

Comment: Success! Now that the file actually gets from point A to point B, trying to re-upload (uploading the same file when it already exists) gives a 500 error, something wrong on line 17. I should be able to play around and fix that, though. Thank you veryveryvery much, I'd be lost without you!

Comment: Do you have errors configured to display? If not, then throwing an exception will just give you a 500 response status without showing you anything. I've updated my answer with an easy way to enable error reporting for development

Comment: You're plain old awesome. Thanks again.